# How to fail the test if Element is found and pass the test if element is not found?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver

I have to develop a unit test which fails if element is present and passes the test if element is not present.

To be detailed, I have a simple form like name, email, address etc. When I click on the save button, error message is displayed if required fields are empty. If error message is displayed then I have to fail the test and if not displayed then pass the test. Is there any solution?

```
try
{
//Click on save button
            IWebElement save_profile = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='form-group buttons']/div/input"));
            save_profile.Click();
//Locate Error Message below the text box
            IWebElement FirstNameError = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form[@class='default form-horizontal']/fieldset/div[4]/div[2]/span/div"));
//I want to fail the test here if above element is found 
}
catch
{
//pass the test if element is not found in try statement
}
```

I think I am going in the wrong direction but couldn't find the solution. Please advice. Thansk in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following is the behavior of "findElement"
If the element you are looking exists, it returns the WebElement.
If the element does not exist, it throws Exception and if not handled properly leads troubles.

So use "findElements"(here observe 's' at the end)
Following is the behavior of "findElements"
It returns a list,
If the element exists, the size obviously more than 0,
If the element does not exist the size will be 0. So you can just put a if condition with size

Here is pseudo code in Java

```
if (driver.findElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='form-group buttons']/div/input")).size()>0)
 //print element exists
else
 //print element does not exists.
```

I hope the above helps.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Do you know how to print messages? I am creating file in c# under unit test. In the above example, I used XPath that will find the error message for required field in form. Your code is working perfectly but I want to pass a message or print a message in if statement where you put comment ("//print element exist")  like "First name required" or "Invalid Email Address" etc. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: It all depends on where you want to print that message. If it console, you can use System.out.println("Your message") - this is in Java, not sure of C#. If you want keep track of logging mechanism use, log4j.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to do this.

Firstly, by using Assert.assertTrue(boolean value);

```
try
{
        //Click on save button
        IWebElement save_profile = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='form-group buttons']/div/input"));
        save_profile.Click();
        //Locate Error Message below the text box
        IWebElement FirstNameError = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form[@class='default form-horizontal']/fieldset/div[4]/div[2]/span/div"));
        //I want to fail the test here if above element is found 
        Assert.assertTrue(false);
}
catch
{
       //pass the test if element is not found in try statement
       Assert.assertTrue(true);
 }
```

Secondly, by using boolean return type if used inside a method.:

```
 boolean isValidated = false;
try
{
        //Click on save button
        IWebElement save_profile = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='form-group buttons']/div/input"));
        save_profile.Click();
        //Locate Error Message below the text box
        IWebElement FirstNameError = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form[@class='default form-horizontal']/fieldset/div[4]/div[2]/span/div"));
        //I want to fail the test here if above element is found 
        isValidated =false;
        return isValidated;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
       //pass the test if element is not found in try statement
       isValidated = true;
       return isValidated;

 }
```

If the method returns true, pass the test and vice versa

Comment: I can't find Assert.assertTrue(). There is no method like assertTrue. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think the correct library was not added org.junit.assert hence the error. Hope this helps